# Facebook login in Opencart

Tags: php, oauth, opencart, facebook-login

I want to implement Facebook login in OC 1.5. More particular - I have Facebook login button on my site and i ask for extended permissions. But after i have user's email I'm not able to log it in my site, because i don't have the password (it is hashed).

What's the secret behind this Facebook auto login for websites? How can i log user in Opencart, using only email?

Again, sorry if I'm missing something obvious. I'm not familiar with OC and MVC-L model but may be there is also way to log user if i pass only email to /catalog/controller/account/login.php.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using opencart then you can log a user in without needing his password . just try this :

```
$this->customer->login($email, $password,TRUE)
```

normally the parameter true is not specified but when you do specify it to true , it overrides the password requirement and you will be able to create a session with user.